# How Can I Prove This Convergent Series Problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a sequence of positive integers such that $∑(1/a_k)$ is convergent.

> Prove that $\ln[(1+1/a_1)×(1+1/a_2)\cdots (1+1/a_n)$] converges as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: Have you tried to relate the new sequence to the old?

Comment: yes but failed to do that

Comment: Which is larger $\ln(1+x)$ or $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(n) = ln \bigl( (1 + \frac{1}{a_1}).... (1 + \frac{1}{a_n}) \bigr) \\$
$u_n$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$ .Lets simlplify our expression :

$  ln \bigl( (1 + \frac{1}{a_1}).... (1 + \frac{1}{a_n}) \bigr) = ln \bigl( (1 + \frac{1}{a_1})+ ... +  ln(1 + \frac{1}{a_n}) \bigr) \\ $

from the well know fact that : $ln(1+x) \le x , \forall x \in [0,+\infty] $

$ln(1 + \frac{1}{a_1}) + .... +ln(1 + \frac{1}{a_n}) \le \frac{1}{a_1} + ... +\frac{1}{a_n} $

applying the limit helps us to conclude using the the *monotone convergence theorem*.